# Inkscape Latex renderer fontsize doesn't match text

Tags: fontsize, inkscape

I want to render Latex equations in my Inkscape drawing with *Extensions → Render → Latex*. I want to render them directly at a specific fontsize for consistency and to match the fontsize to the figure dimensions.

The problem: The Latex output is way larger than the native Inkscape text (see image). Both are set to 8pt.

Question: How can I get consistent fontsize between native text and Latex text/equations?

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a very common problem with the Inkscape extension. See [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1604183) for example. This looks like an issue with the extension rather than anything directly to do with LaTeX. I'd find a different way of doing what you want.